# unable to spot the SQL syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, syntax-error

whenever i try to insert, delete and update i get the following  syntax error. but after I close the exception jdialog and restart the application the data is either inserted, update and deleted

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  mariaDB server for the right syntax to use near 'Customer' at line 1
```

**Insert query**

```
try {

            String sql = "Insert into Customer(ID , FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DOB, Gander, Address, City, PostCode) "
                    + "values (?, AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),"
                    + "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),?,AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),"
                    + "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'),"
                    + "AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'uk112'))";

            pst = newconn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, jTextFieldID.getText());
            pst.setString(2, jTextFieldFirstname.getText());
            pst.setString(3, jTextFieldMiddlename.getText());
            pst.setString(4, jTextFieldLastname.getText());
            pst.setString(5, ((JTextField)txt_Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            pst.setString(6, Gander);
            pst.setString(7, jTextFieldAddress.getText());
            pst.setString(8, jTextFieldCity.getText());
            pst.setString(9, jTextFieldPostcode.getText());

            pst.execute();
            newconn.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
```

**Update query**

```
try{

    String value1 =  jTextFieldID.getText();
    String value2 = jTextFieldFirstname.getText();
    String value3 = jTextFieldMiddlename.getText();
    String value4 = jTextFieldLastname.getText();
    String value5 = ((JTextField)txt_Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText();
    String value6= Gander.toString();
    String value7= jTextFieldAddress.getText();
    String value8 = jTextFieldCity.getText();
    String value9 = jTextFieldPostcode.getText();    
String sql = "update  Customer set FirstName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "MiddleName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "LastName= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "DOB=?,Gander= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "Address= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "City= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112'),"
        + "PostCode= AES_ENCRYPT(?,'uk112') where ID=?";

    pst = newconn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, value2);
    pst.setString(2, value3);
    pst.setString(3, value4);
    pst.setString(4, value5);
    pst.setString(5, value6);
    pst.setString(6, value7);
    pst.setString(7, value8);
    pst.setString(8, value9);
    pst.setString(9, value1);
    pst.execute();
    newconn.close();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is updated");

}
catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

**Delete query**

```
  String sql = "delete from Customer Where ID =?";
        try{

           pst= newconn.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1, jTextFieldID.getText());
           pst.execute();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deleted");
       }
       catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
       }
```

Comment: The sql syntax looks right for these three examples. Please show how you invoke them.

Comment: Try using `executeUpdate` instead of `execute`.

Comment: i have edited and included the more info

Comment: i just did it now still unable

Comment: Also, close the statement before closing the connection. After that, I don't think there is another error in your code.

Comment: i closed both the connection and the preparedstatement  and i changed to to update instead of execute still unable to find the syntax error. p.s thanks for your effort

Comment: Are you 100% sure that when you run this SQL **all** involved Swing components already got their values?

Comment: yes all of them are involved otherwise the values would not be added to the database, its just i receive the error when i try to add, delete and update and after i close the error dialog and reopen the application i can see the altered data

Comment: you're using MariaDB?  Have you tried using the MariaDB JDBC driver instead of the mysql one?